# Updating from 7.34 to 7.35 after successfull update, drush status shows version 7.34?

Tags: drush, updating, security

Recently i tried to upgrade my site from 7.34 to 7.35 everything when successfully but when i go to status report or executing drush status command it shows that im still on drupal 7.34.

These are following screenshots: Result of drush up --security-only (same with drush up drupal)

[image]

And this screenshot shows drush status just after the update:

[image]

Any suggestions whats wrong?

Thanks in Advance
Tee

Comment: Does it say the same thing in your Drupal administration status page?

Comment: Yes it's the same says drupal 7.34 database is up to date and etc but if i would run cron it would say there is a drupal upadate available and i will be able to update it to 7.35 again ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a file permissions issue.  See:

[Can't update drupal core to 7.27](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110619/cant-update-drupal-core-to-7-27)

Drush should give an error message here, instead of pretending to work.